# MYSQL: Where all values in joined table are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have two tables `A` and `B`.

Table A

```
id name

1  first row
2  second row
```

Table B

```
id table_a_id voided

1  1          true
2  1          true   
3  2          false
4  2          true
```

So, I want to select all rows from table `A`, only if all entries from table `B` marked as voided.

I started with simple query

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE b.voided = true
```

and now I'm stuck, the query returns both rows which is logically correct, how to rewrite this query, please?

Comment: Try thinking about it this way: select all rows where no result is not voided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON a.id = b.table_a_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN voided THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fee658f3e125fa1b0eaa9365a07b3b13)**

---

Even simpler(without `CASE`):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON a.id = b.table_a_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
HAVING SUM(NOT voided) = 0; 
-- HAVING NOT SUM(NOT voided);
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a as a
where not exists (select *
                  from table_b as b
                  where a.id=b.id and not b.voided);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table_a 
where id not in (select table_a_id 
                  from table_b 
                  where voided = false );
```